# "undefined symbol: opus_multistream_surround_encoder_create" when calling opusenc or ffmpeg

Tags: opus

On Ubuntu 20.04, I had two operational copies of opus-tools 0.1.10-1 (amd64) and ffmpeg 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 (amd64). I installed lame 3.100-3 (amd64) and opus-tools / ffmpeg stopped working with the following errors:

```
ffmpeg: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.58: undefined symbol: opus_multistream_surround_encoder_create
opusenc: symbol lookup error: opusenc: undefined symbol: opus_multistream_surround_encoder_create
```

I uninstalled lame and got the same messages. Then I used the `--auto-remove` option to remove any dependency and faced the same issues. After that, I uninstalled and reinstalled opus-tools and ffmpeg and that didn't help. Almost giving up, I followed [this FFmpeg-user thread](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2018-September/041327.html) and executed ldconfig. No luck either.

Finally, I tried building and installing opus-tools from the sources but got the following message:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (ogg >= 1.3) were not met:

No package 'ogg' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables OGG_CFLAGS
and OGG_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: There isn't quite enough information to provide a specific answer here, but this is a websearch result for this issue, which appears to stem from loading an opus library that is older than the one that ffmpeg was built with.
For me, my older opus library was a system package, and my ffmpeg built manually, and I needed to specify the path to my newer libopus library when building ffmpeg (`--extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib`). (The ogg devel package can be installed normally to build opus).
At runtime, a quick fix is likely to do `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a backup of your files and reinstall ubuntu 20.04.